# using devise gem, how my admin works as both an admin and a user in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my project I'm using 'devise' gem. Here, I have two models, one for user and another for admin. Now I want my admin to work both as an admin and a user.

Here is my controller main_controller.rb:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
  end

  def about
  end
end
```

In my controller `:authenticate_user!` is working, so when I signed in as an admin, it will accept my authentication.

My model admin.rb file:

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

My model user.rb file:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

How can I do that? Please give me your advice.

Thanks,
Mezbah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inheritance.

In ActiveRecord, it is impemented by adding a column type:string to your model.

```
rails g migration add_type_to_users type:string
```

Then, you will have :

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,:confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

and

```
class Admin < User
end
```

Admins will have total access to users interface

Comment: please another advice

Comment: What does return you 401?

Comment: that return, "Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-24 22:59:59 +0600"

Comment: try to find your devise routes and work out with that (you certainly have both routes for users and admins, skip admin's route